# SIGABRT error in C++

Tags: c++

I am getting a SIGABRT error when I compile the following code.(PRIME1 problem of spoj).
Link of the problem is http://www.spoj.com/problems/PRIME1/. It runs well on codeblocks but spoj returns SIGABRT error. Can someone explain the reason?

```
int main()
{

    long long k,x,j=0,size,l=0,p=0,q=0,r=0,s;
    cin>>size;
    int a[(2*size)];
    cout<<endl;
    for(int i=0; i< (2*size); i++)
    {
        cin>>a[i];
    }
    if( size == 1)
    {
        p=a[1];

    }
    else
    {
        do
        {
            if(a[l+3]>a[l+1])
            {
                p=a[l+3];
            }
            else
            {
                p=a[l+1];
            }
            l=l+2;
        }while(l<2*(size-1));
    }
    cout<<p;
    long * b = new long [p-1];
    for(long long i=0;i<p-1;i++)
    {
        b[i]=1;
    }
    b[0]=b[1]=0;
    s=sqrt(p)
    for(long long i = 2; i <= s; i++)
    {
        if(b[i] == 1)
        {
            for(long long j = i*i; j <= p; j = j + i)
            {
                b[j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    while(r<(2*size))
    {
       for(long long i = a[r];i < a[r+1];i++)
        {
            if(b[i] == 1 )
            {
                cout << i << "\n";
            }
        }
    cout<<endl;
    r=r+2;
    }
    delete [] b;
}
```

Comment: To start with, `int a[(2*size)-1];` is (1) not legal C++ (VLA is a GCC extension) and (2) miscalculating the size of the array.

Answer (score 0):

You initialize `a` to `2 * size - 1` elements...

```
int a[(2*size)-1];
```

Yet you write `2 * size` elements.

```
for(int i=0; i< (2*size); i++)
// ...
```

Your loop should be:

```
for(int i=0; i< (2*size-1); i++)
```

Next...

```
if(size == 1)
{
    p=a[1];
}
```

If `size == 1` then you allocated an array of `2 * 1 - 1 = 1` element, so `a[1]` is an invalid access (you only have `a[0]` as arrays are 0-indexed).

You then have stuff like this:

```
if(a[l+3]>a[l+1])
```

Which loops until `l == 2*size-1`, so `l+3` is invalid as soon as you hit `2 * size - 1 - 3`.

Basically you just have a lot of places where you're reading or writing past the end of an array or not ensuring proper initialization and invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: My understanding is that with those websites they guarantee that the input is in the range specified so you don't have to do extra checking on that.

Comment: @T.C.: Fair enough, it was more of an aside. I removed it.

Comment: Debugger shows a sitrap error at delete statement. Can u please explain why sigtrap is arising there..?

Comment: @user3757655: Because of all of the cases of undefined behavior previous to that line or code? There are many problems with your code, don't focus completely on the one line that throws the error.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing array element accessing outside bounds

Array size `2*size-1` So elements from 0 to `2*size-2`

But in your for loop you are going upto `2*size` thus accessing `2*size-1` which is outside bounds

Answer (score 0):

```
int a[(2*size)-1];
```

This is not legal C++ code (it's using a GCC extension), but it obviously compiled, so we'll let that slide. You are accessing your array out of bounds in the following loop and all over the place later on, which is undefined behavior - you need an array of size `2 * size` to read in all the supplied parameters. Although given that they guarantee that `size <= 10`, you might as well just declare it as `int a[20];`

But that probably didn't cause the crash. What caused the crash is probably this line:

```
long * b = new long [p-1];
```

What's `p`? Well, let's just consider the easy case of `size = 1` where you set `p` to `a[1]`, or the second number you read in. What's the bounds on that number?

The questions says that the bound is `n <= 1000000000`, or 10<sup>9</sup>. Your `new` can be requesting as much as 8GB of memory, depending on the value of `sizeof(long)` in the system you are using. The allocation is almost certainly going to fail, throwing a `std::bad_alloc` exception that causes `std::abort()` to be called as you don't have any exception handling code.

Comment: 'p' is the largest number that we have given as input. I used sieve of Eratosthenes to solve the problem.So i have found out all the primes till 'p'

Comment: @user3757655 Your do-while loop actually doesn't do that correctly; but that aside, you are still trying to `new` up an array that can be as large as 4GB (assuming 32-bit) given the limits provided, which simply will not work.

Comment: Do while is designed as the even numbers are greater than odd numbers for the given problem statement. So what can be the alternative of 'new' ?

Comment: @user3757655 Your do-while loop needs to compare a number with `p` if you want to get the maximum. Right now it's just storing the larger of the last two `n`'s. The answer to your second question is to redesign your solution. You don't have the space to sieve up to 1G numbers, and you don't have to.

Comment: Thank you. Will do that.